# sed delete unmatched lines between two lines with bash variable

Tags: bash, sed

I need help understanding a weird problem with sed, bash and a while loop.

MY data looks like this:

-File 1- CSV
`account,hostnames,status,ipaddress,port,user,pass`

-File 2- XML - This is a sample record set for two entries under one account

```
<accountname="account">

<cname="fqdn or simple name goes here">
<field="hostname">ahostname or ipv4 goes here</field>
<protocol>aprotocol</protocol>
<field="port">aportnumber</field>
<field="username">ausername</field>
<field="password">apassword</field>
</cname>

<cname="fqdn or simple name goes here">
<field="hostname">ahostname or ipv4 goes here</field>
<protocol>aprotocol</protocol>
<field="port">aportnumber</field>
<field="username">ausername</field>
<field="password">apassword</field>
</cname>

</accountname>
```

So far, I can add records in between the respective account holder from File1 to File2. But, if I need to remove records that no longer exists it does not work efficiently since it wipes other records from different accounts, ie it does not delete between a matched accountname.

I import from File 1 into File 2 with a while loop in my bash program:

```
-Bash Program excerpts-
//Read File in to F//
cat File 2 | while read F
do

//extract fields from F into variables
_vmname="$(echo $F |grep 'cname'| sed 's/<cname="//g' |sed 's/.\{2\}$//g')"
_account="$(echo $F | grep 'accountname' | sed 's/accountname="//g' |sed 's/.\{2\}$//g')"

  //  I then compare my File1 and look for stale records that are still in File2

        if grep "$_vmname" File1 ;then
                continue
        else
// if not matched, delete between the respective accountname

sed -i '/'"$_account"'/,/<\/accountname>/ {/'"$_vmname"'/,/<\/cname>/d}' File2
```

If I manually declare _vmname and _account and run

```
sed -i '/'"$_account"'/,/<\/accountname>/ {/'"$_vmname"'/,/<\/cname>/d}' File2
```

It removes the stale records from File2. When I let my bash script run, it does not.

I think I have three problems:

1. Reading the variables for _vmname and _account name inside a loop makes it read numerous times. Any better way to do is appreciated.
2. I do not think the sed statement for matching these two patterns and then delete works like I want inside a while loop.
3. I may have a logic problem with my thought chain.

Any pointers, and please no awk, perl, lxml or python for this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Have not you tried to insert some `echo` lines in order to trace the value of some variables inside the loop? Have you tried to run manually the erasing `sed` command and checked it works?

Comment: Stock advice: do not manipulate XML data using line-oriented tools like `sed`. Use XML-aware tools like `xsltproc` and `xmlstarlet` instead.

Comment: Yes, running the sed statement outside of the loop works fine and tracing with echo's shows that my _vmname and _account fields are being read into and parsed three times for each record.

Comment: Try changing the while loop to a redirect rather than a pipe, `while read F; do  ... done < File2`. Also, your grep in the conditional, do you mean `grep -q`? Perhaps you want something like: `grep -q "$v_name" File1 && continue`

Comment: Your XML is not XML.

Answer (score 0):

> and please no awk

I appreciate that you want to keep things simple, and I suppose awk seems more complicated than what you're doing.  But I'd like to point out you have so far 3 grep and 4 sed invocations *per line* in the file, to process *another* file *N* times, once per line.  That's *O(mn)* using the slowest method on the planet to read the file (a while loop).  And it doesn't work.

> I may have a logic problem with my thought chain.

I'm afraid we must allow for that possibility!

The right advice is to tackle XML with an XML parser, because XML is not a regular language and so can't be parsed with regular expressions.  And that's *really* what you need here, because your program processes the whole XML document.  You're not just plucking out bits and depending on incidental formatting artifacts; you want to add records that aren't there and remove those that "no longer exist".  Apparently there is information in the XML document you need to preserve, else you would just produce it from the CSV.  A parser would spoon-feed it to you.

The second-best advice is to use awk.  I suppose you might try an approach like:

1. Process the CSV and produce the XML to be inserted.
2. In awk, first read the new input XML into an array keyed by cname,  Then process the XML target *once*.  For every CNAME, consult your array; if you find a match, insert your pre-constructed XML replacement (or modify the "paragraph" accordingly).
3. I'm not sure what the delete criteria are, so I don't know if it can be done in the same pass with step #2.  If not, extract the salient information somehow.  Maybe print a list of keys from each of the two files, and use comm(1) to produce a list of to-be-deleted.  Then, similar to step #2, read in that list, and process the XML file one more time.   Write anything you delete to stderr so you can keep track of what went missing, from what lines.

> Any pointers

Whenever you find yourself processing the same file N times for N inputs, you know you're headed for trouble.  One of the two inputs is always smaller, and that one can be put in some kind of array.  `cat file | while read` is another warning signal, telling you *use awk* or any of a dozen obvious utilities that understand lines of text.

You posted your question on SO two weeks ago.  I suspect no one answered it because you warned them away: preemptively saying, in effect, *don't tell me to use good tools*.  I'm only here to suggest that you'll be more comfortable after you take off that straightjacket.  Better tools, in this case, are the only right answer.